There are some techniques that i'm missing out in creating this IPC more robust and consistent?
[C language]\
Hello there! I'm trying to do a simple IPC between two files ".c" but I'm facing some unexpected output.

I'm compiling the server file, nothing wrong, the PID is clearly printed.
I'm compiling the client with PID of the server and a string of 100 chars
-> usleep(3000) -> expected output
-> usleep(100)  -> undefined behaviour.

Here are the scripts:

server.c

void    handle_signal(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
        static unsigned char     ch = 0;
        static int               idx = 0;
    
        (void)context;
        if (signo == SIGUSR1)
            ch <<= 1;   
        else if (signo == SIGUSR2)
            ch = (ch << 1) | 1;
        idx++;
        if (idx == 8)
        {
            kill(info->si_pid, SIGUSR1);
            write(1, &ch, 1);
            idx = 0;
        }
}
int main(){
        struct sigaction sa;
    
        printf("Server PID: %d\n", getpid());
    
        sa.sa_handler = (void (*)(int))handle_signal;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sa, NULL);
    
        while (1) {
            pause();
        }
        return 0;
}


client.c

void    handle_input(int signo){
    static int  number = 0;

    if (signo == SIGUSR1)
        printf("Received letter %d!\n", ++number);
    else
        number = 0;
}

void    handle_output(char **input, pid_t pid){
    int             i = 2;
    int             j = 0;
    int             bits = 8;
    unsigned char   send;

    while (input[i])
    {
        while (input[i][j] != '\0')
        {
            while (bits-- > 0)
            {
                send = input[i][j] >> bits & 1;
                if (send == 0)
                    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
                if(send == 1)
                    kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
                usleep(100);
            }
            bits = 8;
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char                *ptr;
    struct sigaction    sa;
    
    if (argc < 3 || !argv[2][0])
        return (printf("Not enough values!\n"));
    ptr = argv[1];
    while (isdigit(*ptr))
        ptr++;
    if (*ptr != '\0')
        return (printf("Wrong pid format!\n"));
    
    sa.sa_handler = handle_input;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

    handle_output(argv, (pid_t)atoi(argv[1]));

    return (0);
}

What I'm missing to control so that my program works with every kind of input? I don't want to use any other includes beside signal and sigaction to send and receive signals :-D Thanks a lot for the help!

What does "I'm compiling the client with PID of the server and a string of 100 chars" mean? Do you mean you're executing it with these arguments?

Signals aren't queued by default. So if you send signals too quickly, some of them may be lost. See the linked question for more details.

Sorry for confuse, I was thinking about executing and wrote compiling because at the time I was also tried different manners to resolve this issue.
I know that aren't queued by default, but also If I'm sending one at the time, the server must treat them one at the time, no? Anyway, there is any good practice/order to write the code lines when dealing with signals? With a few prints I've seen that neither the char from handle_signal is not constructed in the right order :-|

You're sending them every 100 ms. If it takes more than 200 ms to process the signal, every other one will be missed.

Signals should generally not be used for rapid communication like this. Use pipes or message queues.

But this is what I don't get it: why in the first chars is displaying the right chars, and then, after I'm executing it once again or are, for example, 100 chars, it displays other values than the one passed. What changes? Because the static variables are handled right..

I thought the difference was whether you used usleep(100) or usleep(3000). The first sends too quickly, so some signals are lost. The second is slower so everything is processed.

There is a manner of coding in which I can't lose signals besides usleep() greater?
I've also tried to calculate the time in milliseconds in which my function handle_signal it's executing, but in vain. It also lose some chars from a long string passed.

Research "realtime signals", they can be queued.

I see variations on this come up every year - must  be a popular assignment in a programming class. It's really a terrible one, as signals are really bad at anything besides saying "something happened". Actually using them to transmit data is something nobody in their right mind would do. The only non-insane approach is using a SA_SIGINFO handler and sigqueue() to send a single int along with the signal, and real time signals so they're queued. But that's never what people are supposed to do in this type of assignment...
